# C# regex capturing only the whole expression and not the individual capture groups

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have this regex to capture type names- first the type name, then the list of generic parameters, and finally the assembly name:

```
(.*?)\[\[(.*?)\]\], (.*)
```

And when I run it against a string like this (a simplified version of the fully qualified name of a type):

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[FrEee.Modding.Formula`1[[System.String, mscorlib]], FrEee.Core]], mscorlib
```

I get only one match on the whole string:

[link](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28.*%3f%29%5c%5b%5c%5b%28.*%3f%29%5c%5d%5c%5d%2c+%28.*%29&i=System.Collections.Generic.List%601%5b%5bFrEee.Modding.Formula%601%5b%5bSystem.String%2c+mscorlib%5d%5d%2c+FrEee.Core%5d%5d%2c+mscorlib)

Why are the three capture groups I defined not matching the individual parts of the string?

Comment: What code are you using to iterate the matched groups?

Comment: Do the $1, $2, $3 columns in the Table tab at the bottom match the parts that you want?

Comment: There are no $1, $2, or $3 columns; that's my problem - only the $0 (the full regex) is being matched. As for iterating the groups, I'm using  `match.Captures[1].Value`, etc.

Comment: If I use that regex on that string I get values for each of your groups. As Jacob implies the bug seems likely to be in the code you are using to get the groups from your match. I've voted to close until such time as the question contains an actual problem.

Comment: The link you provided to regexstorm does have $1, $2 and $3 for me. If you're not seeing that its weird. And the regex captures the whole thing. So there is only one capture. You want to be looking at `match.Groups` for the groups within your capture.

Comment: Yep, `match.Groups` is what I need!

Comment: @ekolis: Cool. If you are willing to spend the time it might be nice to update the question with the code you were trying to use and then add an answer with the corrected code in. Completely understandable though if you don't want to take the time now you have your answer. Just thinking it might help the next person who confuses captures and groups...

Answer (score 1):

I was using this code to access the captures:

```
match.Captures[1].Value
```

When I should have used:

```
match.Groups[1].Captures[0].Value
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, it looks like you should [make the parameter wildcard greedy](https://regex101.com/r/pN9xEZ/2/) so that it doesn't trip up on the inner brackets:

```
(?<type>.*?)\[\[(?<parameters>.*)\]\], (?<assembly>.*)
```

Comment: Yep, I noticed that the other day!